# JQuery doesn't reads dynamic created element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

Well, I think this gonna be a simple question, but I'm unable to realize how Jquery loses/is not able to find attributes of the element:

Javascript:

```
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    Cells[i]=document.createElement('div');
    Cells[i].id = "Cell"+String(i);
    Cells[i].className = "CellClass";
    if (i==0)//Let's look the fist one (neverminds which one).
    {
        alert(Cells[0].className);//This would alert: "CellClass" (without quotes).
        alert($("#Cell0").className);//This would alert: "undefined" (without quotes).
        //Another way:
        alert($(Cells[0]).className);//This would alert: "undefined" (without quotes).
    }
}
```

for the question, class .CellClass is not relevant itself, neverminds which attributes define.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: try `$("#Cell0").attr("class");` instead of `$("#Cell0").className`

Comment: Perfect guys. Really really quick. You're incredible!. Awesome.

I need to learn more about jQuery wrapper objects for avoid make the same error anymore.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($("#Cell0").attr('class'));
```

Will work

Answer (score 6):

`$(Cells[0])` returns a jQuery wrapper object not a dom element reference so it does not have properties like `className`.

You can use any one of the following method

```
Cells[0].className
$(Cells[0]).prop('className')
$(Cells[0]).attr('class')
```

**Also make sure that the element is added to the dom structure before the jQuery selector `$("#Cell0")` is executed** else the element will not be found in the dom lookup

Comment: Thank you Arun, that's has been really clarifier.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Not withstanding Arun's answer about the difference between jQuery objects and DOM objects, you'll also find that `$("#Cell0")` won't actually work until `#Cell0` has actually been placed in the DOM, by adding it to a parent node.

Comment: Yes, for get "#Cell0", I needed first place it in the Dom. If I put "1" in the if condition, for see "Cell0" element, to secure myself it has been created and placed in the DOM yet, then it works perfectly. Thank you for the point!.